# What is the setter property for a mouse up action in wpf button style?

Tags: wpf, button, triggers, mouse

I am trying to change button look at each state, now i have `IsEnabled` `IsPressed` `IsMouseOver`, but what is the `Tigger Property` for mouse left button released?

```
<Style x:Key="GoogleGreyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!--Some setters here-->

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <!--Some setters here-->

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <!--Some setters here-->

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I would say it is an event and not a property

Answer (score 0):

You need more in your style for anything to display but try this for the event:

```
<Style x:Key="GoogleGreyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="Button_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!--Some setters here-->

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <!--Some setters here-->

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <!--Some setters here-->

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for that:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            ...
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```